# What is meant by "spectral resolution of 0.5 GHz"?

Tags: spectroscopy

I sometimes see spectral resolution uses unit Hz. But spectral resolution is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_resolution) and its unit is given as the smallest difference in wavelengths(Δλ) that can be distinguished at a wavelength.

What is the equivalent way of saying "0.5 GHz spectral resolution" in terms of wavelength(Δλ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispersion relation can be written as $c=\lambda f$. Differentiate both sides using the product rule and the fact that $c$ is a constant:

$$0 = d\lambda f + \lambda df$$

Solve for $d\lambda$:

$$d\lambda = -\lambda \frac{df}{f}$$

Usually people consider the absolute value and express $\lambda$ through $f$:

$$|d\lambda|=\frac{c}{f^2}|df|$$

Comment: On the right side of your last equation c is known. And the term “spectral resolution of 0.5 GHz” represents |df| correct? So can we say that at around 100GHz “spectral resolution of 0.5 GHz” means (300000000/(100GHz)^2)*0.5GHz  as dLambda? An example of this sort would be super helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, that's all correct (besides of the missing units in the light speed value). The term spectral resolution might refer to both $d\lambda$ and $df$ depending on the context, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

The 0.5GHz says that how your spectrum analyzer can differ two frequencies. It depends on aperture size in type of analyzer you are using. so to understand this in wavelength you just need to use f*(lamda)=c and del(lamda)=c*del(f)/(f)^2 which will give you what is the smallest separation in wavelength it can detect.